# Accessing WINAPI methods within C

Tags: c, winapi

I would like to access the DeleteFile WINAPI system call 
within my C Code. When checking the Windows File Management
functions it outlines me just the C++ Syntax:

```
C++

BOOL WINAPI DeleteFile(
  __in  LPCTSTR lpFileName
);
```

What I would like to know is how I can use this function within
pure C code? I have never done anything with the winapi yet, do I just
need to include winapi.h to get it work?

Comment: What book or Web site are you using to learn from? I find it hard to believe it didn't demonstrate this.

Answer (score 7):

Yes. The Win32 API is a pure C API. I assume the example is labelled as "C++" because more development is done in C++ these days than in C.

Answer (score 3):

Win32 is a C API, so just go ahead and include windows.h and call the function.

Answer (score 3):

> do I just need to include winapi.h to get it work?

Yes, or actually "windows.h".

You'll also need to link to the right DLLs, for example the [API reference for DeleteFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa363915(VS.85).aspx) says that it's defined in `Kernel32.dll`: so you'll need to link your program to `Kernel32.lib`.

Answer (score 0):

Yep, you can call it from C, simply `#include <windows.h>`your IDE will have the most used libraries linked and you will be able access most of the WinAPI, however there are some functions that will require you to include more then just windows.h and link more libraries, so always keep an eye on the documentation at https://msdn.microsoft.com/